# How to Transpose an rdd in pyspark (list is not a matrix)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have an rdd where the list of strings are ['abc', 'ccd', 'xyz'...'axd']

When I "print rdd.take(2), I am expecting it to return me ['abc', 'ccd'], but instead it gives me everything. I am very new to spark or python so please forgive me if this is a dumb question. is there a way to transpose this list to rows?

Eventually i need to convert this into a dataframe and insert into a hive table.

Here is a pice of my code

```
domainsrdd = zonerdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + ' ' + y).map(lambda a:     (a[0], a[1].split(' ')))

print domainsrdd.take(2)

[(u'COOL', [u'shirtmaker.cool', u'videocandy.cool', u'the-happy-factory.cool', u'vic.cool', u'atl.cool',...... u'booze.cool'])]

def sampler(l, tldvar):
    tld = l[0]
    domain_data = l[1]
    domains = []
    ct = tldvar.value[tld]
    for item in domain_data:
        domains.extend([item])
        if len(domains) == ct:
            break
    return domains

domainslist = domainsrdd.map(lambda l: sampler(l, tldvar))

print domainslist.take(2) # still returns everything

[[u'shirtmaker.cool', u'videocandy.cool', u'the-happy-factory.cool',...])]
```

Long story short, i am trying to loop thru a set of domains grouped by tld's and producing a sample of those domain names, tldvar is a dictionary which has set of domains i need to return for a specific tld. TLD = com, net, org etc!

Comment: take(n) always returns the first n elements of the dataset. You may have called the collect() method, since the entire dataset seems to have been returned. Could you add some sample code to your post?

Comment: Just updated the formatting

Answer (score 0):

`domainslist` is of type `RDD[Array[String]]`, so when you do a `take`, you're going to get an `Array[Array[String]]`. Which, in your case is filled with arrays that are never limited down based on what you are saying (`len(domains) == ct` is never `true`)

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved - I have used a flatmap instead of map. Basically this worked

```
domainslist = domainsrdd.flatmap(lambda l: sampler(l, tldvar))
```